# no window or output from rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been running rviz (as well as the rest of the ROS stack) just fine on one computer, but now I can't get rviz to run on a second computer.  Unfortunately, I don't get any output from rviz on the second computer, so I am having trouble figuring out how to debug it.

The second computer is pretty vanilla.  (It's a 64-bit Intel PC running Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo.)  If I run `rosrun rviz rviz` after starting `roscore`, I get absolutely nothing.  It just hangs, without output.  (I've also checked my .ros/log files.)  If I run without starting `roscore`, I get this

```
[ INFO] [1450375110.690702198]: rviz version 1.11.10
[ INFO] [1450375110.690762620]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
```

and a dialog box telling me that `roscore` isn't running.

I've tried the `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` environment-variable trick from the rviz troubleshooting page, and that didn't help.

The only relevant differences I can think of between the two computers is that the second computer has two monitors and an AMD video card, versus a single monitor and Intel integrated graphics.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222720/no-window-or-output-from-rviz/) by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The differences you list are significant, and could certainly be responsible for your issues. Without more information, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help. Things you could try to identify or workaround the issue:

1. Try different drivers for your graphics card. In my own experiences, I've had terrible luck with AMD cards and Linux. I often run into issues with the drivers provided by `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates`, and the performance of the `radeon` drivers leaves something to be desired. The Ubuntu wiki has a [pretty good tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) on switching to various versions of the `fglrx` drivers. If you're already using `fglrx` you could [revert to the radeon](http://askubuntu.com/a/68312/37292) drivers.
2. You could fallback to using your CPU's built-in graphics.
3. Try disconnecting the second monitor. I have encountered issues in the past where multiple monitors cause issues. If this fixes the issue, it is possible that different settings in your Xorg.conf file would allow you to use both monitors with your ATI card.
4. It seems odd that you would get no messages of any kind when you run rviz. If you can obtain some sort of error logs, backtraces, something, it would help people narrow down your errors. If you're really not getting anything in your terminal, you could try looking at `dmesg` for possible issues. There may be messages printed to `/var/log/` files. You could try running  `rviz` in `gdb` with a command like `gdb -ex run /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-12-17**:
Thank you!  Using gdb I found that it was getting stuck loading the Oxygen theme for GTK, during the creation of the QApplication object.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-12-17**:
That's great! So switching to a different theme resolved the issue?

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-12-17**:
I'm sorry, I should have made that clear.  Yes, I uninstalled the theme and used the default.  It's working now.  Thanks again!